# byte[] length changes when inserted into mysql database, only first byte is sent

Tags: java, mysql, serialization

My little test-program is writing a serialized object into a mysql database, then retrieving it again, casting it to an object, then running it's `toString()`. I'm trying to get the whole idea about Blobs on databases. (The object is a goat, that has a name, age and sex) My problem is that when I insert it into the database, it only sends the first byte, and not the rest.

First I write the object:

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO goats(goat) VALUES (goat = ?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    out.writeObject(goat);
    byte[] dataAsByteArray = b.toByteArray();
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(1 , new ByteArrayInputStream(dataAsByteArray), dataAsByteArray.length);
```

Then I retrieve it again:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT goat FROM goats");
    rs.next();
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
    byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()); 
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (bis);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `goats.goat` actually a `BLOB`?

Comment: what is 'goat' in first snippet?  2) where are you checking that the length is 1?

Comment: @Dan Yes, goats.goat is a BLOB. :)

Comment: What does `blob.length()` return? If you look at the data with a database browser instead of code, how much data do you see?

Comment: @I82Much goat is my object, which I described. (Has 3 variables, and implements serializable) I'm printing the length outside of the snippets, as it's not really that important.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Aha! Good suggestion. There's only 1 byte stored. A 0.
So my problem is that it doesn't store it properly in the database in the first place.

Comment: @Martin: Okay - so it sounds like it's the storage part which is failing. What's the length of `dataAsByteArray` when you store it?

Comment: Oh, and have you tried using setBytes instead of setBinaryStream? Just as an experiment.

Comment: Also, 98 bytes isn't very much. Can you just try `setBytes` instead of `setBinaryStream`?

Comment: Just tested again, and for some reason, the dataAsByteArray.length is 94 before it's inserted into the database.
I have tried with setBytes instead, with same result.

Comment: Silly question: Did you executed the PreparedStatement? "pstmt.execute()"

Comment: @bruno Yes. :) I did execute and close after the snippets.

Comment: @Martin: What's the declaration of the field like in the schema? It doesn't have a maximum length of 1 by any chance, does it?

Comment: @Jon It's a BLOB, so there's not much to say as to max length is there? If there is, where can I find such a thing?

Comment: @Martin: I don't know - I haven't use mysql for ages, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jon Aww, shucks. Well thanks for trying at least, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Does it help if you do a `out.close()` or `out.flush()`?  You really shouldn't assume that all implementations of `ObjectOutputStream` are going to flush content to the underlying output stream unless there's an explicit flush there.

Comment: @Mike Tried with flush and close as well, same result sadly.

Comment: Answer has been found, thanks all for the assistance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out.close();
```

Seems to be missing.

---

The answer seems to be that `goat=?` is a boolean comparison yielding 0 or 1; a typo.

`VALUES(goat = ?)` should be `VALUES(?)`.

Comment: A question from my side; `VALUES( goat = ?)` is correct? I always did `VALUES(?)`. Doesn't that insert true 1 or false 0?

Comment: That solved it. :D Thanks a lot! Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it? :)